# Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only date with $m-%d format

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

i'm trying to plot a geom_ribbon with y = consumption and x = date with a format %m-%d.

```
df$date <- as.Date((paste(df$annee, df$mois, df$jour, sep='-')), "%Y-%m-%d")
df$monthday <- as.Date(df$monthday, format = "%m-%d")
g1 <- ggplot(df) + 
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max, x = monthday), data=df, group = 1) +
      geom_line(aes(y=mean, x=monthday), group = 1) + 
      scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%d", date_breaks = "1 month") 


library(gridExtra)
pdf("plot.pdf")
grid.arrange(g1, ncol=1)
dev.off()
```

But when I run the code, I get the below error :

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please add a small example of your dataset.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: I suggest to edit your post and add the output of `dput(df)`. It would be easier for the SO community to help you.